# Responsive menu opening on request

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, nav

I've written this js so the menu is responsive but doesn't break when js is not enabled.

I have 2 menu lists each inside their own nav element. For tablet and mobile devices I want only a menu button (first item in the list with ) to show but no list until the menu button is pressed.

At the moment the first list hides on opening the page but the other list is permanently showing. However, clicking either menu button does the same job of showing the first list. Neither nav has an id or class.

Why is only one of the lists responding?

This is the JS (its in the head)

```
function showLists() {
$('.nav').show();
$(".menu").hide();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 450) {
    $('.nav').hide();
    $(".menu").click(function () {(
        showLists()
        )})
    }
});
```

Comment: "Neither nav has an id or class" well you need to use `$("nav")` to select all `nav`-elements. `$(".nav")` means "all elements having nav class". And btw could you create a fiddle plz http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks. That really helped as it made me realise I'd given all the link elements a class of nav. A bit embarrassing but extremely useful

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are going after a basic toggle navigation.  A great starting point for basic and even more advanced responsive solutions is [RWD Patterns by Brad Frost](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html).

Also, you should in mostly all solutions be able to get away with defining only ONE navigation list and using CSS and JS to manipulate it to behave responsively.